# windows 10 problems on toshiba satellite C655D

Tags: touchpad, windows-10-upgrade

I had Windows 7 Home Premium but then upgraded to windows 10. Now my touch pad won't work. I don't have a touch screen since my laptop is from 2011. Is there a way to get my touch pad working again? Or will a usb mouse work? I just really really want my mouse on my computer to work. Please help me.

Comment: Borrow a mouse to try it?

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed the same problem on my Toshiba C655D's fresh upgrade from Win7 to Win10. Using a USB mouse, do the following at your own risk. R-Click on Taskbar / Choose Task Mgr / Startup Tab / locate ETD - Elan items / R-click on Enabled & change to Disabled. Reboot. My trackpad & mouse buttons acted correctly immediately afterwards. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the printer driver (Devices, Mouse and Track-pad, Additional Settings).  Go to ELAN and click "*disable when external USB pointing device*" - now if you put a USB mouse in it should work.  When you take it out, the track-pad works.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your touchpad is newer versions might be borked. Try the last version that worked.

My HP Stream 11 runs a synaptics touchpad. HP has version 19 for windows 10. Its completely broken and won't work. I installed version 18, which was the last version for windows 8 and it works. You might want to try installing the last driver for windows 7 or 8 that worked and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Elan Touch Pad Driver from official website [Touch Pad Driver](http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=3133792)

Answer (score 0):

Have look at your intel settings in device manager. if it says I/O error, reinstall the correct Intel settings for your device and the touchpad will work correctly.

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding some step-by-step instructions and screen shots.